# What is the difference between "a spade" and "a shovel"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

[In the Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shovel_1?q=shovel), a spade has a squared metal part and a shovel has a metal part with curved edges. This is the picture from Oxford dictionary.

[image]

In Cambridge dictionary, a shovel has a squared metal blade ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shovel)). This is the image of a shovel from Cambridge dictionary.

[image]

Also in Cambridge dictionary, a spade has a curved metal blade ([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spade)). This is the image of a spade from Cambridge dictionary.

[image]

What is the difference between "a spade" and "a shovel"?

Comment: The bottom two pictures are both shovels, see the lower one is among the list at the top. A spade typically has a *straight* edge and is stronger. It is also a cutting tool, for roots and compacted ground, whereas a shovel is used for scooping up loose material. The bottom one is perhaps a sort of 'in-between' tool, as carried by a military vehicle, with some capability as both a spade and a shovel, but not ideal for either job.

Comment: [tag:american-english] And now I'm confused even more. I always thought the flat ended shovel was called a flat-blade shovel, and the one with the rounded tip was a spade-shovel (because it looks like a [spade from a deck of playing cards](https://www.google.com/search?q=spade+card&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic37CNxub-AhXSk4kEHXE1DFsQ0pQJegQIDBAB&biw=1920&bih=929&dpr=1)).

Comment: I hope one thing you take away from the answers is the difference isn’t clear even to many native English speakers!

Comment: There is a shovel in the Cambridge dictionary that has a squared blade, but that doesn't means that in the Cambridge dictionary, a shovel has a squared blade.

Comment: FYI - These appear to be BrE based references.  In AmE a fork is a pitchfork (doesn't matter if it's flat or cupped, it's still a pitchfork), a strimmer is a Weed Whacker or a trimmer, a spade is pointed at the end, and a shovel is flat at the end.

Comment: @EllieK I thought to say the same thing, but apparently a [pitchfork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork) is different than a [garden fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_fork), and the image more appears to be the latter.

Comment: English seems to be losing the word spade as a digging implement.

Comment: The final picture is a spade.  The penultimate picture is a shovel. End of story.

Comment: In the topmost image, the fourth label **is incorrect**, it's a typo. It's just that simple. As you can clearly see, the Cambridge pair of images/labels are correct.

Comment: P.S. The rake on the left is what my family (NAE) calls an "earth rake". The one on the right is what we usually picture when we say just "rake".

Comment: NZ antipodea here -  Queens Engrish spoke. ||  A spade is for creating holes or cuts and MAY be used for transferring already loose material. || A shovel is for transferring material (shovelling material) and may be used for  producing cuts or holes. Each is better at what it is designed for than the other one's task.

Comment: @Joshua, English as spoken in England, is definitely _not_ losing the word spade as a digging implement.

Comment: @BWFC Joshua appears to spik American English.

Comment: Variant on an old joke: How do you get an (ethnic) confused? Show him a spade and  a shovel, and tell him to take his pick.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference is in the purpose of the tool, as described in the dictionary definitions you have found.

A spade is for digging holes in the ground. It has a strong, flat blade, typically straight-ended (despite Cambridge's picture).

A shovel is for picking up and moving earth, coal, manure etc. The blade usually turns up at the sides so that stuff doesn't fall off so easily.

I found [this website](https://garrettwade.com/blog/shovels-and-spades-whats-the-difference/) - which shows a square-tipped spade even though it says that many people think of them as having a pointed tip!

Comment: I'd say this answer is probably true, but I'm skeptical that most English speakers are actually aware of this technical definition of the words. My family (speaking American English) uses "shovel" to refer to both shovels and spades that are large and require two hands to use. We use "spade" to refer to small, one-handed digging implements. My point is that OP probably shouldn't expect everyone to follow the definition given here, even though this definition is correct.

Comment: Growing up in the American Southwest, we had both a spade and a shovel in our garage with the purposes you've laid out, but the spade was pointed as in the Cambridge picture to help break hard, dry ground. Trying to dig in with a straight-bladed shovel was usually an exercise in futility.

Comment: To further @THummus's point, I speak American English and *spade* is not in my active vocabulary at all (except as a playing card suit).  Big tools like this are always *shovels*, and the little ones for gardening are *trowels*.

Comment: A pointed tool is usually best for digging holes, a flat-edged one is best for lifting/moving material and edging garden beds. Is a spade usually used for digging and edging shallow garden beds? A flat-edged implement would probably be the wrong tool to dig a deep hole or a long trench - I'm surprised you describe the spade as for digging holes, when the ground is broken more easily by a pointed shovel, and the dirt more easily moved by a shovel's typically larger size and concave shape.

Comment: @Juhasz I think most people would associate the word "spade" with the pointy ones, specifically *because* of the playing card suit.  It's weird to me that it's the opposite.

Comment: -1 for incorrect matching of the definition to the tool. Anyone who has ever done a significant amount of digging knows that a spade/round shovel is what you use to break ground, and a square/flat shovel is used for picking up and moving bulk materials.
The flat edge of the square shovel allows the user to scrape against a hard, flat surface like concrete without catching it, and to pick up all of the material in the shovel's path. The pointed edge of the spade/round shovel is used to penetrate dirt, and because it is curved, it will not pick up material at ground level on the edges.

Comment: @zaen Anyone who's done significant amounts of digging knows that square tip spades dig looser soil, like gardens, and pointed spades dig compacted or stony soil. Meantime a shovel is defined by its high sides, as the answer says. Anyone who's moved significant amounts of bulk material knows that a square tip shovel moves sand and gravel nicely, but a pointed shovel is much better for moving heavy bulk material like ballast stones or coal.

Comment: I’m very surprised at all the Americans commenting that this basic distinction (breaking ground vs moving soil) is unknown to them. I’m absolutely no gardener or digger, but even I know the difference! @zaen It’s very hard to tell what exactly you’re saying, because your terms are mixing unrelated things. The tip of the blade can be straight or pointed on both spades and shovels, but spade blades are _flush_ with the handle (so ‘flat’), while shovel blades are _angled_ on the handle and curve up at the sides (so ‘round’). Spades are for digging, shovels for moving.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, the word *spade* has probably fallen out of use in the US to avoid confusion with the racial slur.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In addition to flush vs angled, spades also usually have a reinforced spine on the blade for stepping on it, while a shovel does not have reinforcements.

Comment: @zaen - My assertion that spades are 'typically straight-ended' comes from my experience of garden tools. With regard to other types of digging, I stand corrected.

Comment: @THummus As a British English speaker I'm familiar with the distinction having used a shovel to dig a hole and a spade to move the earth when I was younger.

Comment: @ThePhoton Several people have mentioned that, so it’s definitely a possibility. I’d never even heard of _spade_ as a racial slur, so to me there’s never been any potential for unfortunate phrasings.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'd say it *was* a racial slur for a while, but that usage has long fallen out of favor even among the types of people who regularly use other racial slurs.  But maybe I don't know - I try to avoid spending too much time around such people.  I have heard it in some older movies, or period films set in the 1800's and early 1900's in the US though.

Comment: But in playing cards, the Spade suit symbols are all rounded not square or rectangular.

Comment: Growing up in Ohio I learned that "shovel" is a generic term for "a roughly spoon-shaped hand tool for moving dirt or rocks". A "spade" is a pointy-ended shovel used for digging holes and cutting through dirt. A "flat-bladed shovel" is one with a squared-off cutting edge used to move dirt, rocks, etc. A "trenching shovel" is a long, narrow shovel used for digging trenches. A "scoop" is a wide, deep shovel used to move grain or other light-weight and easily-penetrated piled materials. And for extra credit: what's the difference between a hay fork, a manure fork, and a spading fork? :-)

Comment: @stackoverblown The shapes of actual hearts, diamonds and clubs don't match the playing card symbols either.

Comment: As a southern British English speaker, I use the words as this answer describes; however, my partner (who is from the north of England) uses "spade" and "shovel" as synonyms - so I think it's regional.

Comment: I would like to add, that a spade used for digging has some kind of "rounded" end in the direction of the handle. So it is possible to place a footh on the blade's edge, or even both, to use the body's weight as additonal power to get it into the ground

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - "I’m very surprised at [ people being all-but unable to use words ]"  You need to stop being surprised, and you should have stopped being surprised, say, about around 1990.  (The fact that you mention "Americans" in this context is irrelevant, all English speakers are now barely functional with language.)

Comment: @Fattie It’s not a matter of being unable to use words. I was surprised because I thought the distinction was universal, and both terms equally frequent. I didn’t know that there were apparently quite large swathes of speakers who either don’t distinguish them or don’t have _spade_ in their active vocabulary at all. When I commented above, only Americans had noted that this was the case for them, so it looked very regional; a few Brits have since said the same, so it’s at least not entirely Pond-based.

Comment: Janus. Just in general you seem to be wildly underestimating how *incredibly* illiterate English speakers are in our historic period (every region), particularly anyone under let's say 25. If you surveyed 10,000 completely random 10 years olds today, I'd guess 80% of them *would never have heard either* of the two words in question, and would simply look blankly at such a photo.

Comment: @Fattie You can find such complaints about "the current generation" going back hundreds of years, if not thousands.  The sentiment that knowledge of how to speak and write properly is expiring is basically constant.

Comment: "It has a strong, flat blade, typically straight-ended" I don't know what planet you live on... But I have never fouund a flat blade particularly good for digging. A pointed or rounded blade works much better. Further sharpening of the blade can make digging even easier (Most spades come dull).

Comment: @THummus have you ever heard the word _trowel_ ?

Comment: I've heard the word before, but no one I know uses it

Comment: Maybe that's because I'm not a gardener, or maybe it's a regional language variation. The point is, not all native English speakers follow the dictionary definitions for these words

Comment: @Questor - The planet that calls [these](https://www.gardenersworld.com/reviews/tools/planting/best-garden-spades/) typical spades. OK, they may have a slight curve.

Comment: For a Danish speaker this discussion is hilarious. We have a common saying in Danish: 'You should call a shovel for a shovel, and a spade for a spade'! (Danish: 'Kald en spade for en spade og en skovl for en skovl!"). See also: https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=spade. Yes. A spade is for digging and a shovel is for moving material (by shovelling). The blade of a spade is straight with the shaft and often heavier then a shovel, which has its blade at an angle with the shaft. A pointed spade is superior in stony soil.

Comment: @NielsHolst In english we have a similar idiom: to "call a spade a spade" means to speak plainly and directly, not avoiding or hiding anything even if it's embarrassing. (Compare to "brutally honest")

Answer (score 12):

In common usage, the terms are interchangeable, though at least in my experience ‘shovel’ is preferred over ‘spade’ in American English (I suspect this has to do with ‘spade’ having significantly more alternative definitions, including possible usage as a racial slur and a handful of uses in animal husbandry that are often not listed in dictionaries).

In technical usage, there are differences but they are subtle.

Formally, a shovel is an implement used for moving loose material such as dirt, gravel, concrete, or snow. The blade (the part that actually holds the material) is usually turned up at the back and sides to prevent whatever is being carried from falling off. The leading edge of the blade may be curved or may be straight, depending on what is being carried. The leading edge of the blade may be sharpened (for example, on a snow shovel, where the sharp edge is used for breaking ice), or may not.

A spade, in this context at least, is an implement used for digging holes. The leading edge of the blade of a spade is almost always sharpened, and may be either straight or triangular (but almost never curved, as that is not especially useful for digging holes), and the blade is typically *mostly* flat, though it will often have a short section at the back that is bent 90 degrees so that you can use your foot to apply extra pressure to cut through roots when digging with it. Spades, by their very nature, are also inherently shovels (you have to move the dirt out of the hole somehow).

It’s also worth noting that these days, *most* shovels made for gardening are also spades, because there is generally no need to have a distinct tool just for moving dirt. By the similar logic, most folding shovels, camping shovels, and entrenching tools are also designed to serve both roles.

Comment: Another place where they are definitely not the same word would be heavy construction equipment.  We still use the term "steam shovel" today (despite the fact they're all diesel hydraulics and not steam powered these days").  A "steam spade" is not a thing.  Nor is a "snow spade" for that matter, since you mention it.

Comment: I would say (in British English, and being keen on tools) that most folding or camping shovels aren't shovels, but spades.  BTW you seem to have a half-finished sentence:*"bent 90 degrees so that . Spades"*

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I remember pictures of the construction of the Panama Canal which showed wonderful steam shovels.

Comment: @ChrisH - I remember also reading of accounts of hand-to-hand fighting in Flanders where British troops invaded German trenches and used their 'entrenching tools' to attack  the troops they found there. A kind of folding spade I think.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey these days, yes, but British WWI tools were different ([Wikipedia has a picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrenching_tool)) resembling an adze with a pick (though the handle was removable to leave a very short-handled spade). Modern ones are very similar to what I carry in my van in winter but similar, with a smaller blade than a gardening spade.

Comment: @ChrisH I guess it comes down to what you consider the requirements to be for a shovel and which ones you’re looking at. I would definitely consider a [Glock entrenching tool](https://eu.glock.com/en/products/glock-entrenching-tools) to be a perfectly serviceable (albeit small) shovel in addition to a spade because of the shape of the blade (and I have used one as such on multiple occasions), though I could not say the same of all the camping shovels I’ve seen (or all of the D-handle tri-fold designs like NATO states tend to use, or the Russian MPL-50).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn that looks much better for scooping than mine, better deserving of the name "shovel" - which [mine](https://www.mcsoutdoorstore.ie/product/gelert-folding-shovel/) (Gelert) also gets

Comment: It was helpfully clarified in a TP book "Goodmountain says, "...Never use spades, Farmers use spades. But I call a shovel a shovel.""  Showing that anyone who needs to dig or move (spade or shovel) will know the name of the action and the tool.  As less people need to know the technicalities it becomes only construction people and gardeners who know which you dig a whole with and which you fill it with (involving manure in the quoted example).

Comment: +1 for “It’s also worth noting that these days, most shovels made for gardening are also spades” because I think that’s where a lot of the confusion comes from

Answer (score 10):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

These words are not at all interchangeable, except perhaps when used figuratively.

A spade is strong and sharp at the leading edge to allow digging in compacted soil.  It often has a flat part at the back which you can step on to push it into the ground.

A shovel is *only* suitable for moving material that is already loose.  It often is curved up at the sides to stop the loose material from falling off, and maybe slightly curved in the middle too, like a spoon.

You can use a spade when you need a shovel, but it will be a bit harder work because its strength makes it heavier and the material will fall of the sides.  You cannot use a shovel when you need a spade, its shape will not allow it to be forced into hard ground.

Comment: I'm surprised by the images of shovels shown here: they are much too straight to be used for shoveling. The ones I've seen look like these:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Skovl.jpg
https://www.joostdevree.nl/bouwkunde2/jpgs/schop_02_schep.jpg

I.e. with a clear curve so that you can easily scoop up stuff with the blade horizontal, without having to awkwardly keep the handle also horizontal and low to the ground.

It surprises me that that curve is apparently considered to be optional; I can't imagine having to shovel using a shovel with a straight handle.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are talking about the Oxford dictionary, maybe you are interested in British usage. But for completeness, I wanted to add American usage. As an American, I don't think I've ever heard anyone call a tool a "spade" in informal speech. "Shovel" is the more common word and "spade" to me sounds like the fancy word, in contrast to @JamesK's comment that "spade" sounds more plain. This seems to be evidenced by the Google ngrams, in that "shovel" seems to have a bigger advantage in American usage.

[image: Google ngram American usage of "spade" and "shovel"]
[[image: Google ngram British usage of "spade" and "shovel"2]

To confuse things further, there is an implement called a "transfer shovel," which looks an awful lot like your description of a spade. I'm going to assume that transfer shovels and spades are distinct if you are well-versed in gardening tools, but the difference isn't obvious to me. Here is a screenshot from Home Depot's webpage:

[image: Home Depot shovels]

Comment: A transfer shovel has a deeper scoop in the blade. This allows it to hold more material so you can transfer piles of whatever faster.

Comment: But "shovel" can also be a verb, whereas "spade" cannot, which inflates the results for "shovel". If you compare "a shovel" with "a spade" the AmE results are much closer.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Good point! Yeah, there some limitations of ngrams since "spade" might also be referring to cards, which is pretty much the only way I hear the word used where I live.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I'd add that, at least conversationally,, "all spades are shovels, but not all shovels are spades."

Comment: I (southern British English speaker) would label those as "shovel, spade, spade" (going from left to right)

Comment: Spade is a completely normal verb. You "spade something out". The OED gives the (rather bizarre archaic) example of "a tool with a shape similar to a spade for another purpose, especially one for removing the blubber from a whale ...", in such context spade is used easily as a verb.

Comment: NZ antipodea here -  Queens Engrish spoke. || Your transfer shove; would never be mistaken for a spade here by people who use such. Your pictures are all shovels. || A spade is for creating holes or cuts and MAY be used for transferring already loose material. || A shovel is for transferring material (shovelling material) and may be used for  producing cuts or holes. Each is better at what it is designed for than the other one's taek.

Comment: As an American, I agree with the southern British English speaker above.  The one with a square edge is a "transfer shovel".  The two with pointed edges are "spades".  I consider "digging shovel" to be a synonym or definition for "spade".  The Oxford Dictionary graphic in the original post has it completely backwards.  Perhaps a typo.

Answer (score 6):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)
There's no big difference.

A shovel tends to be used like a big spoon to carry materials.  The etymology comes from words meaning "push away".  They "shove" things around. So shovels tend to have deep blades, sometimes with curved-up edges (to stop things from falling off). Some shovels have a point.  They might be used by builders for moving concrete from a wheelbarrow into a mould.

Spades tend to be used for cutting into the soil to turn it over.  They tend to have flatter blades. They are used by gardeners for trenching and aerating the soil. They might have a flat or pointed tip, though more often they are flat.  Spades tend to be slightly smaller than shovels.

The distinction between spades and shovels is associated popularly with the proverb "call a spade 'a spade'" (Which means to use plain and direct language instead of fancy, euphemistic or deceptive alternatives). With "shovel" being the "fancy" alternative.  (actually this is a mistranslation of the Greek *en skaphen skaphen legein*)

Ninety-nine percent of the time, you could use either word.

Comment: In the UK, there is, I think, a division between gardening-tool nerds who correct you if you use the 'wrong' word, and everybody else, who don't care and use the words interchangeably. Also I think 'shovel' can be a verb, and I'm pretty sure you can shovel up sand, gravel, etc with a spade if that's the only tool you have, and aforesaid nerds aren't present.

Comment: Having thought a bit, I think the casual UK interchangeability works one way, some people happily call a spade a shovel, but not so many the other way around. When I was a kid we had a coal-shovel on the hearth for getting the lumps of coal out of the scuttle and into the fire (tongs as well) and it would not have been right to call it a 'coal-spade'.

Comment: I think the *"He calls a spade, 'a spade'"* phrase comes from the playing card suit: ♠, which of course resembles the pointed end of a spade-type shovel as well.  But that phrase refers to playing cards, not actual shovels.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I'm surprised to find Wikipedia doesnt suggest that.  It came from an old Greek expression that mentions troughs.

Comment: @JMac Yeah, just looked that up myself and was surprised to see cards not even mentioned.  Wiktionary does mention cards, but only as a pass-through to the use of the phrase as a racist slur, but the phrase does long pre-date that history.  Personally I immediately think of cards when hearing that phrase, but I guess the actual etymology is a bit more complex.

Comment: It had certainly never occurred to me that it might have anything to do with playing cards. A spade is simply a commonplace, literally 'down-to-earth' implement.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman  We are **both** wrong.  It comes from a mistranslation (by Erasamus no less!) of a greek proverb  which literally means "call a bowl 'a bowl'"  (*en skaphen skaphen legein*)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman There's an old English regional trope that Northerners say 'I call a spade a bloody shovel!'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I know the expression, not as a Northern stereotype but as a comment on people who are not just direct but go out of their way to describe things in crude language.

Comment: -1  for saying "There's no big difference." A shovel is for moving stuff, eg "Coal Shovel", whereas a spade is for gardening work, eg an "edging spade" which has a tiny, round blade, and is no use at all for moving soil.

Comment: -1 from me as well.  When you say "99% of the time" it seems you live in a world where words for real physical objects are only ever used figuratively.  If I need to dig a hole and ask for a spade, and someone assumes it means the same as a shovel and gives me a shovel, I cannot do my work!  If you never need a either spade or shovel in your daily life then yes, they are interchangeable, but for anyone who ever has need of the physical object, they are very different and must not be mistaken - and surely someone wouldn't use the word if they weren't interested in the object it refers to.

Comment: "The etymology comes from ..." who cares?  The etymology doesn't define the meaning (which is what a learner needs).

Comment: James, I have to agree with Tom that your "99%" comment is frankly bizarre. Every single house I've ever been in, with a garden, yard or bit of lawn, and a garage with a pile of old tools in it, has had both a spade and a shovel.  If my good wife says to me "Could you finally get off your butt and bring me the shovel" - and I brought her the spade - she'd think I'm weird.  (Same if a spade is required.)  They're as completely distinct as **plier V. scissors** or **jeep V. pickup** or **mop V. broom**. If I brought shovel for spade, I'd probably be met with "WTF, are we on a steam train?"

Comment: @JamesK - ***"The distinction between spades and shovels is associated popularly with the proverb "call a spade 'a spade'" "*** I'm sorry, but this is incredibly nonsensical on many levels.  It's so silly and unusual for you to write something like this that I'm not even going to begin unpacking it. You really should edit that away, or it will be out there for chatGPT for the next million years!!!  My goodness!

Comment: @JamesK !  My goodness!  :)  :)   ***"They "shove" things around."***  Absolutely incorrect. They shovel things, which has no connection, in any way, even vaguely, to shoving.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I believe shovels and spades are used by a lot of professionals beyond "gardening-tool nerds".

Answer (score 5):

[german](/questions/tagged/german)

In German, we have the same distinction. We have a "Spaten" and a "Schaufel". Usually, spades are made from thicker material with a bent-over, sturdy back edge to step on. It is used to dig into compacted soil. The blade's shape is not the defining feature; we have a "Gaertnerspaten", i.e. "gardeners' spade" that often has a pointed digging edge like your second example, while the "Spaten" without qualification is usually with a straight digging edge. You might even find "sawblade"-like features on spades, usually on one side, to cut away roots while digging.

Shovels come in all forms and sizes, from relatively small shovels for cement and sand to huge ones for manure and snow.

Note that "shovel" is also used in a more general sense that includes both spades and shovels as used before.

Answer (score 3):

A shovel is for ... wait for it ... shoveling.

A spade is a paddle-like shape.

**Note that in the Oxford photo, the label "spade" is, simply, wrong, a typo. They'll fix it in a later edition.** The pointy for-earth-breaking tool shown is overwhelmingly, pedagogically, a spade.

(Yes, yes, yes you can sometimes use a knife to shovel, you can sometimes use a laptop to shovel, you can sometimes use a peony to shovel. Whatever. The pointy tool shown is a cartoon, pedagogic, spade.)

The label on the Oxford photo is just a typo, there's absolutely nothing else to see here.

Answer (score 2):

With tens of thousands of companies creating thousands of slightly different types of shovels and spades, there was always going to be some overlap with the purpose of the tool and some variations in the naming, especially when translated into different languages.

Since there are spades almost identical to shovels, the easiest way to remember it is probably to think about what you will use the tool for.

Digging? It's a spade.
Shoveling? It's a shovel.

That being said, people use the tools at hand, so you find people shovel with a spade or dig with a shovel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Many  British people will also be unclear. If they have never had cause to use both implements, they may not know that the other word is not a synonym.

(After they have tried to do work intended for one with the other, they should be getting an inkling ...)

A spade has a flat blade and is for digging or for breaking up compacted soil.

A shovel has a blade turned up at the edges and is for moving loose stuff from a heap into a wheelbarrow or similar. It holds more, especially if the stuff is loose (for example, gravel). It's not usually as sturdy as a spade and is likely to break if you try to dig with it. It's typically also wider.

A spade may have a pointed blade or a flat one.

There are edge cases. There's a trenching spade (or shovel?)  with a long narrow sturdy blade turned up at the edges, used for digging a trench just a few inches wide and over a foot deep in which to bury a pipe or cable.

And then you can investigate mattocks, azadas, digging hoes, etc....

Answer (score 0):

In general usage, in my part of the southern US, a spade is long and narrow, and a shovel is wider and shorter.

But that said, I think most people here would consider a spade to be a *specific type* of shovel. Anything that's basically a cupped blade used to move earth is a shovel, and a spade is a particular type of shovel with specific uses.